# How to store multiple selections from InfoPath form into different fields of SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a InfoPath form which has a lookup and allows user to select multiple options from the lookup. 
After selection, the values are getting stored in a single field of my SharePoint list, separated by semicolon. I want them to be stored as different fields. Is there a solution possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your InfoPath form you would have to create separate fields and then use function to populate them with the selection from the lookup and then promote those fields to SharePoint list.

Comment: Can you please tell more about this? Or provide links? Thank you for your help

Comment: The user can select as many options from the list as he wants. So I cannot create many fields in the InfoPath form at once.

Comment: you wrote 'I want them to be stored as different fields' so you will have to create as many fields equal to how many options users can select, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: My doubt is that, if a user selects only 5 out of, say, 10 options, then 10 fields will be created in the SharePoint list right?

Comment: well your requirement is "I want them to be stored as different fields" so yes if you have 10 options you will need 10 fields.